# Twilio - Digium: Sending FAX using T.38

Tags: twilio, sip, fax

I do not know if this is the appropriate forum for asking help for my issue, in case it is not i would like to apologies for any inconvenience.

So, the story goes somehow like that, i have purchased a number from Twilio in order to use it for sending/receiving faxes. Our Telephony System is a Digium switchvox and i have also configured a Cisco CUBE to the edge of my network.
When we try to send a fax, we can see that the packet reaches Twilio, but there is an error:

Error - 32102
SIP: Bad SDP

Please let me know if you had the chance to make it work.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Can I ask how you've set everything up to send faxes from a Twilio number? Were you following our documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio don't support t.38
You can't archive that through twilio as a provider

Comment: This answer is a stub and should rather be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), since short answers like this may be considered low quality. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment. If you don't have enough reputation, read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on how to contribute if you don't have enough reputation yet.